# ExtJS4 - How to convert Ext.form.Basic to HTMLFormElement

Tags: html, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

A third-party Javascript function requires native HTML `<form>` to be passed in.  I have a `Ext.form.Basic` object.  How can I convert it to a native HTML form?

Answer (score 2):

There is a config for `Ext.form.Basic`, `standardSubmit` (boolean).  If this is set to true then when `submit()`  is executed it will submit a standard html form.  [Check out sencha docs for more info](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-cfg-standardSubmit)

Comment: I need to submit the from to a different domain.  Setting `standardSumit:true` does not help.  The owner of the site has provided javascript to submit the form using JSONP.  The example call to the function is `AAA.process(document.forms[0], {......})`.  It seems I have to pass a native HTML form to this function.

Comment: @user2074056 hrmm, jsonp would require a script tag with data required, i would wager that the `process` method is taking the `forms` elements and constructing a `jsonp` request.  ExtJS has the ability to submit `JsonP` requests, [check out this link](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.JsonP-method-request).  Here is a [general gist](https://gist.github.com/weeksdev/8220969) i created that i usually use to submit